# Is it possible to make points in a line chart of Chart JS 3.7.0 look like a donut?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

the version of Chart JS is 3.7.0

I am looking for a way to make my chart's points look from this:

[image]

to something like this:

[image]

I found out that there is an option in this library where you can set the points to a certain shape. *e.x*: `pointStyle: 'rectRot'` will make the points appearance look like this:

[image]

Is there an option or a way to achieve what Im looking for? (Check the second picture).

Thanks in advance!

My chart's `javascript`:

```js
const data = {
  datasets: [
    {
      backgroundColor: 'black',
      borderColor: '#2d84b4',
      borderWidth: 2,
      data: [
        { x: 'Dec 27', y: 0.204 },
        { x: '01:00', y: 0.234 },
        { x: '02:00', y: 0.274 },
        { x: '03:00', y: 0.234 },
        { x: '04:00', y: 0.304 },
        { x: 'Dec 28', y: 0.506 },
      ],
      fill: false,
      pointBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#2d84b4',
      pointHoverBorderColor: '#2d84b4',
    },
  ],
};

const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    animation: {
      duration: 0,
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
      //Do not display legend.
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: {
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 2,
        },
        grid: {
          display: true,
          drawBorder: false,
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          drawTicks: true,
          tickLength: 4,
          type: 'time',
        },
      },
      yAxes: {
        grid: {
          drawBorder: false,
          drawTicks: false,
        },
      },
    },
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 5,
      },
    },
  },
};

// Initialize the Chart.
const myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), config);
window.addEventListener('beforeprint', () => {
  myChart.resize(600, 600);
});
window.addEventListener('afterprint', () => {
  myChart.resize();
});

//Disable all animations!
myChart.options.animation = false;
myChart.options.animations.colors = false;
myChart.options.animations.x = false;
myChart.options.transitions.active.animation.duration = 0;
```

Comment: Do you have a reproducable example with jsfiddle or something because when I use your config it seems to work fine with what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/cznukhw8/5/

Comment: Can you edit the fiddle to make the same point formation but bigger on hover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The points seemed to work just fine with your transparent background, only on hover you setted a normal background again so the `pointHoverBackgroundColor` should also be transparent.

To make the point bigger on hover you can use the `hoverRadius` and to make the line have the same width you can use the `pointHoverBorderWidth`:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: 'black',
      borderColor: '#2d84b4',
      borderWidth: 2,
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
      pointHoverBorderColor: '#2d84b4',
      hoverRadius: 10,
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2
    }]
  },
  options: {}
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```